# What is the easiest way to convert 123456789 value to 123.456.789 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  a < p > with 123456789 value

I need to convert my < p > value into 123.456.789 number. What's the easiest way to do this in js?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve. 123.456.789 is not a floating point number. Are you trying to make something like `123,456,789`?

Comment: Show us what you ve tried so far so that we can help you improve your code.

Comment: `123456789..toLocaleString('it')` (I picked `it` because I know `it` uses `.` for thousands separators and `,` for decimal "comma", so would output *the string* `"123.456.789"` .... `123456789..toLocaleString('en')` would guarantee `"123,456,789"` - if you just want to use the users locale ... just `123456789..toLocaleString()` should use their locale rules

Answer (score 3):

Try it using regex. The `match()` function creates an array and `join('.')` will join the array elements to the required output.

```js
str = "123456789";

str = str.match(/.{1,3}/g).join('.')

console.log(str)
```

Comment: fails if the string length is not a multiple of 3, like `1234`

Comment: @Thomas _"fails if the string length is not a multiple of 3, like `1234`"_ That is not requirement of present Question, no? What "fails"?

Comment: @Thomas I checked. "1234". I got 123.4. Is that a fail in this case?

Comment: @Thomas _"yes, it should be `1.234`"_ How did you reach that conclusion? And not `123.4`? Certainly not from text of original Question itself?

Comment: It "should" be? Dude it works the way OP wants. Let it go. You have already downvoted me. If you have a better answer please post it.

Answer (score 2):

Try Using this function.
Useful for any number and for any delimeter you pass through.

```js
  function formatNumber(n, d) // n = number, d = delimeter
    {
        // round to 2 decimals if cents present
        n = (Math.round(n * 100) / 100).toString().split('.');
        var
                myNum = n[0].toString(),
                fmat = new Array(),
                len = myNum.length,
                i = 1, deci = (d == '.') ? '' : '.';
        for (i; i < len + 1; i++)
            fmat[i] = myNum.charAt(i - 1);

        fmat = fmat.reverse();
        for (i = 1; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                fmat[i] += d;
            }
        }
        var val = fmat.reverse().join('') +
                (n[1] == null ? deci + '':
                        (deci + n[1])
                        );
        return val;
    }

    var res = formatNumber(123456789,'.');
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d{3}(?=\d{6}|\d{3}|$)/g` to match three digits followed by six digits, three digits or end of string, chain `.join()` to array returned by `.match()` with parameter `"."`

```js
var str = "123456789";
var res = str.match(/\d{3}(?=\d{6}|\d{3}|$)/g).join(".");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex combined with `html` will be enough to get it to work beautifully:

```js
$(".telephone").html(function () {;
  return $(this).html().match(/[0-9]{3}/g).join('.');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="telephone">123456789</p>
```

Comment: You are correct but we're (or just me?) taught to code with greatest performance in mind so choosing going through jQuery when it's just as easy in vanilla isn't as 'optimal'. It also comes down to preference but from what I've seen opinions tend to lean toward what I said

Answer (score 0):

I has use some jquery code, pls try this! hope this can help you! :)

`$('.number').text(function () {
      var txt = $(this).text();
      return txt.replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
 });`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.number').text(function () {
      var txt = $(this).text();
      return txt.replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="number">123456789</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const convert= (str)=>{
let newStr=""
let pointer=0;

while(pointer < str.length){

 newStr += str.charAt(pointer)

 if(str.charAt(pointer) % 3 === 0 && pointer !== str.length-1){
      newStr += "."
    } 
 
pointer++
}

console.log(newStr)

}



convert("123456789");
```